# How to change html changes inside a html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was creating a button which will increase number on button click.

Like this:

```
<button>Create</button>
<p id="p"></p>
<script>
var i = 0
$('button').click(function() {
  $('p').html(i);
  i++;
});
</script>
```

It worked perfectly.

Then i added `localstorage` to it.

The code is like this:

```
<button>Create</button>
<p></p>
<script>
var i = 0
$('button').click(function() {
  $('p').html(i);
  i++;
});
$(function() {
   var  = document.getElementById('p');
      $("button").click(function() {
         localStorage.setItem("comment4", $("p").html());
      });
   if (localStorage.getItem("comment4")) {
      .innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("comment4");
   }
});
</script>
```

And it also worked perfectly.

Here is a demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wo5b3h7z/1/)

**My doubt is that, How can i change the `var i = 0` to the next number?**
So that if I open it with notepad(or something else) I have to see the `var i =` `the next number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly this must suffice

```
var i = localStorage.getItem("comment4") || 0;
```

Although its impossible to change the contents of a file without a server side language

Comment: No matter which language you use. I just want to change it.

Comment: Then you should probably use php or aspx for which you must be running a webserver. I would suggest you to make use of filesaver.js api to set the contents of the file and automatically download it to view it in notepad but this doesnt change the contents of the html file..